# How to display an image from a matrix of pixels?

Tags: python, image, gtk, gtk3

In Python and Gtk3, When I have an image file, I can display that image like this

```
image = Gtk.Image()
image.set_from_file(file_name)
```

But If I have a matrix like the following

```
[[ 10, 120,  38,  75, 189],
 [200, 122, 130,   0,  29],
 [255,  11, 102, 222,  18],
 [ 36, 118, 199,  45,  26],
 [231, 218,  12,   5, 156]]
```

which represents the pixels of an image in grayscale, is there a method that allows to display that image directly from that matrix instead of having to save it to an image file and then load that file?

Comment: [Looking at the docs](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkimage.html) there's also `set_from_pixmap(pixmap, mask)`, `set_from_image(gdk_image, mask)`, `set_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)`, would any of those work?

Answer (score 1):

I've only used Gtk2, but I agree with Nick's suggestion to check out [gtk.gdk.Pixbuf](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gdkpixbuf.html).

From the linked doc:

> A gtk.gdk.Pixbuf object contains the data that describes an image
>   using client side resources. By contrast a gtk.gdk.Pixmap uses server
>   side resources to hold image data. Manipulating the image data in a
>   gtk.gdk.Pixmap may involve round trip transfers between a client and a
>   server in X11 while manipulating image data in a gtk.gdk.Pixbuf
>   involves only client side operations. Therefore using gtk.gdk.Pixbuf
>   objects may be more efficient than using gtk.gdk.Pixmap objects if a
>   lot of image manipulation is necessary.

In particular, take a look at the `pixbuf_new_from_array()` method. To do the reverse, you can use the `get_pixels_array()` method. These methods give you access to the Pixbuf's `pixel_array` attribute.

You can render a Pixbuf using `gtk.gdk.Drawable.draw_pixbuf()`.